# Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'orderInCateogry' in package 'android'

Tags: android

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:checkableBehavaior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_red"
            android:orderInCateogry="1"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/red_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_green"
            android:orderInCateogry="2"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/green_string" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_blue"
            android:orderInCateogry="3"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/blue_string" />
     </group>
 </menu>
```

Why is it not working? The error says what's in the title:
1. Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'orderInCateogry' in package 'android'
2. Error:(6) No resource identifier found for attribute 'checkableBehavaior' in package 'android'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, as it turns out. My spelling was wrong.

`android:orderInCateogry="1"
    <group android:checkableBehavaior="single">`

It should be `android.orderInCategory` and `android:checkableBehavior`. I feel so stupid now after this.